# Инициализация и возврат объекта из метода

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Имеется абстрактный суперкласс `ClassName` с тремя наследниками, отличающимися между собой конструкторами, а так же четвертый класс, который передается в конструкторы в качестве параметров.
Хотелось бы создать метод, который случайным образом выбирал бы, экземпляр какого из классов создать, создавал бы и возвращал его. При попытках вернуть из `if` компилятор выдавал ошибку `Missing return statement`, при попытках вернуть после выполнения проверок `if` компилятор выдает ошибку `Cannot resolve symbol exemplar`. Со `switch case` тоже ничего умного не вышло.

```
static ClassName choice(Somthing something){
    int min = 1;
    int max = 3;
    int value = (int)((Math.random()*max) + min);
    if(value==1){
        ClassName1 exemplar = new ClassName1(something);
    } else if(value == 2){
        ClassName2 exemplar = new ClassName2(something);
    }else if (value == 3){
        ClassName3 exemplar = new ClassName3(something);
    }
    return exemplar;
}
```

Comment: В Java слово class является зарезервированным и ключевым. Вы не сможете назвать им переменную

Comment: @Flippy я назвал его здесь так для примера. сейчас переименую.

Comment: @АлександрЕфремов `return exemplar;` переменая ничего не хранит, нужно при создании `exemplar = null;`, также  вы можетев ифах сразу возращать елемент, пример ` return new  ClassName1(something);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вынесите возвращаемое значение из `switch/case` или `if/else`, инициализируйте ее в зависимости от чего-то. Возвращайте.

Кстати, возвращаемое значение должно совпадать с `ClassName`

```
static ClassName choice(Somthing something){
    int min = 1;
    int max = 3;
    int value = (int)((Math.random()*max) + min);
    ClassName clazz = null;
    switch(value){
        case 1:
        clazz = new ClassName1(something);
        break;
        case 2:
        clazz = new ClassName2(something);
        break;
        case 3:
        clazz = new ClassName3(something);
        break;
    }
    return clazz;
}
```